# md5 check on inputstream without saving as file

Tags: java, spring, md5

I am developing a page to upload files. I am using spring framework 3 multipartFile. I only want to save this uploaded file if it has been changed form its original version in the server.  Is there a way I can do MD5 check without saving this uploaded file in a temporary location?

Thanks,
Vasanta

Answer (score 5):

You can use `MultipartFile`'s `getBytes()` method to read the contents as byte array, and then:

```
byte[] uploadBytes = upload.getBytes();
MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] digest = md5.digest(uploadBytes);
String hashString = new BigInteger(1, digest).toString(16);
System.out.println("File hash: " + hashString);
```

---

However, according to [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html) the file can potentially still be saved to a temporary folder (but Spring would clean it up afterwards):

> The file contents are either stored in memory or temporarily on disk.