# Upload multipart file to AWS without saving it locally

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wrote a Rest API that accepts `MultipartFile`. I want to upload the files that come in to Amazon S3. The problem is that I don't know a way other than first saving it to the local system before uploading it to S3. Is there any way to do so?

Right now, there is an issue in saving the file locally and I'm looking for a work around: [Multipart transferTo looks for a wrong file address when using createTempFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187261/multipart-transferto-looks-for-a-wrong-file-address-when-using-createtempfile/50187444?noredirect=1#comment87406347_50187444)

Comment: Very basic question but useful :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.Use `putObject` which consume  `InputStream` as param.
Here is sample code.

```
public void saveFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws AmazonServiceException, SdkClientException, IOException {
    ObjectMetadata data = new ObjectMetadata();
    data.setContentType(multipartFile.getContentType());
    data.setContentLength(multipartFile.getSize());
    BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey", "secretKey");
    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).build();
    PutObjectResult objectResult = s3client.putObject("myBucket", multipartFile.getOriginalFilename(), multipartFile.getInputStream(), data);
    System.out.println(objectResult.getContentMd5()); //you can verify MD5
}
```

You can find javadoc [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata-)

Comment: Nitin, thanks buddy, very simple and exact answer.

Comment: how do you verify the MD5 ? most of the documents say it may or may not be the same as what you upload. Is there a way to know the MD5 before you start uploading the file.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928233/md5-check-on-inputstream-without-saving-as-file