# Hi, Iam working on a Java Code to upload Files into S3 bucket. But instead of uploading a file to S3, i need to write some data into a file name in S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-s3-client

I am using aws-java-sdk-s3 dependency to use S3 libraries in my spring Boot App. I have written some demo code to upload a file to S3 bucket

```
upload(bucketName, key, fileName, s3client);
```

But my scenario is different, i am getting some data from DataBase and i need to write this data to a fileName and upload this file to S3 bucket, How to achieve this using AmazonS3. Below is my code i tried to do. Iam just skipping the S3 client creation here to make it simple

```
public void upload(String fileName,String folderName, List<Map<String,Object>> jsonData){
 String bucketName= “myBucketName”;
 String toFile = folderName + “/” + fileName;
 FileOutputStream os = null; 
 try{
os = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
byte[] strToByte = jsonData.getBytes();
os.write(strToByte);
client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, toFile, new File(fileName)));
    }catch(IOException e){
Log.error(e.getMessage);
   }finally{
os.close();
}
 }
```

This code is working fine, but a local copy of this file is creating in my local machine and that file is being uploaded to S3 bucket. Like this i have millions of files. I cannot store all of these in local System. So is there a way to write the data directly to a file and upload it to S3 without being stored anywhere.

Comment: Write the file to memory and then upload the stream...or delete the local file after each upload competes...I'm kind of confused by this question. "So is there a way to write the data directly to a file and upload it to S3 without being stored anywhere." ---Both methods above do this and are pretty standard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload multipart file to AWS without saving it locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248710/upload-multipart-file-to-aws-without-saving-it-locally)

Comment: @Chaitanya This is fine, if i use Multipart File, but i need to write my data to multipartFile, how will it be possible. If you see my code above, i have a file name and json, i need to write that json by creating a file with file name and then upload that to S3

Comment: @ViaTech writing millions of files to a memory and then again deleting all those files after uploading to S3 will consume lots of time. So is there a way to upload the data by creating a file with the desired fileName directly in S3 bucket, without storing it anywhere

Comment: @vyas yes, as stated in my intial comment...a stream would be that way

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html) code to upload an object using a **byte[]**:

```
 private S3Client getClient() {
        return S3Client.builder()
            .region(PhotoApplicationResources.REGION)
            .build();
    }

public void putObject(byte[] data, String bucketName, String objectKey) {
        S3Client s3 = getClient();
        try {
            s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .key(objectKey)
                    .build(),
                RequestBody.fromBytes(data));
        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```